# What are the development differences between Apache products and Redhat Fuse?

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

We have been using the Apache ActiveMQ and Camel products for a while now but want to look at a good base ESB.  I've been reading the Redhat site about Fuse but have been unable to find a good summary of the significant differences between Fuse and Apache for coders.

From a designer's/developer's point of view what are the significant differences between Fuse and the Apache Camel and ActiveMQ that we have been using?  I get the lovely overview stuff, FuseIDE and the ESB management tools.  But I really just want to know of the differences at the code level,  i.e.  does it introduce more useful Camel endpoints?  are there additional libraries of genuinely useful things that will make my life as a designer/coder easier?  are there any pitfalls to look out for?

I just need a few pointers to help me in my search, not a tome.  Or better still a quick link to a document that goes over all this (ever hopeful :o) !)  I have a short time to form a view to go forward on or the opportunity will pass me by.

Thank you.

SK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the code level there is "no" difference. The process is that we develop on the Apache projects, and sync the code changes to Red Hat / Fuse git repos. There we cherry pick the changes we want to go into our branches, to keep the product stable. As well backport fixes to older branches if our customers need that / etc (eg you can influence that)

The products from Red Hat is also supported on a much longer timespan than the community support from Apache. There is a guranteed lifetime which you can find here: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/

There is only a few additional Camel components from Fuse / JBoss Fuse products, which is part of the open source project Fuse Fabric (http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/) which is part of the JBoss Fuse products. Fuse Fabric is in the process of being donated to Apache ServiceMix, so it can benefit that community as well, allowing ServiceMix to bundle Fabric out of the box as well. Fabric has a few Camel components that allows sending messages to a any Camel endpoint that load balances automatic in a clustered environment / cloud environment. And there is another Camel component for selecting a master, and only run the route on the master node, and if the master dies, then another node takes over.

> I also think that this move is a testimony of the open source
>   willingness the Fuse team has and continues to have. We do as much as possible
>   in the opening. For example the new project - hawtio (http://hawt.io/)
>   is also fully open source, ASL license, github project, anyone can contribute/fork etc.

And the JBoss Fuse product allows to patch itself in production. So if you need a hotfix asap, we can provide a fix as a .zip file which can be patched using a built-in patch tool in the product. This isn't possible from Apache.

A few links for further material (from our old site and the jboss community site)

- http://fusesource.com/enterprise-support/support-offerings/
- http://fusesource.com/community/apache-committers-and-fuse/
- http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse
- http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/04/apache-camel-web-dashboard-with-hawtio.html

Disclosure: I work for Fusesource / Red Hat.

Answer (score 1):

On a code level, the difference is very small, if any at all.

What you get from the commersial RedHat package is support, a package that has been tested and operational benefits (that you mention).

It's all about what happends after the code is made - when you put your things to production and the coder is not still around to handle incidents.

Comment: Thank you.  This pretty much confirms the impression that I am getting.  I will talk to Redhat about support here in New Zealand.

Answer (score 1):

Apache ActiveMQ and Camel are open source projects. Redhat fuse bundles them and possibly many other components into one package and so it can be used as one ESB package. I see the biggest difference as the support that you can get. You can get support for something that your organization has not produced. And the tools that comes with the package does help during development and maintenance in my view.

Comment: Thank you; are the tools that you refer to here the ESB web portals and IDE extensions?

Comment: yes, some of the tools that i am aware of are the IDE and web gui for monitoring and installing bundles.