# Is Fuse Fabric free to use in production? Can I use it with ServiceMix?

Tags: apache-camel, cluster-computing, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, fusefabric

Fuse Fabric http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/index would offer usable features for clustering my ServiceMix solution and it's Camel routes.

- Is Fuse Fabric free to use in production? I see mention of Apache 2.0 license in FAQ, but that does yet guarantee that it can be used for no cost
- Can it be used with standalone ServiceMix or only with Fuse ESB/JBoss Fuse?

I did see related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163165/1469083 that says "Fuse Fabric is in the process of being donated to Apache ServiceMix...", what does this mean exactly and what is the status of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric is an OpenSource project, so if you want to use it with ServiceMix, you can. Licence is only involved if you want support from RedHat by buying http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-esb-enterprise/.

Good luck with it,
Gergely

Answer (score 2):

Fuse Fabric is a 100% free and open source project. Its ASL 2.0 licensed. You can grab the source code and use it anyhow you like accordingly to the ASL 2.0 license terms.

The source code is hosted on github at: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse

> Fuse Fabric is provided out of the box in the Red Hat JBoss Fuse
>   product. And this product requires a subscription to use in
>   production. You can download and try JBoss Fuse and use it as a developer as long you want etc. But a subscription is required for production. Remember this is a product from a commerical vendor, eg Red Hat, and its a business. And someone need to pay the salaries to the great minds that work on these projects. After all we all need food and beers :)

Though to reiterate you can grab the source code for fuse fabric from github and use it anyhow / fork it / contribute to the project etc. We love contributions btw.

And you can build your own binaries to use form the source code. Or grab the binaries from maven central, which is released from time to time.

> And Fuse Fabric is *still* in process of being donated to Apache. This
>   kind of donation takes time, so have patience. Such a process involves layers, and whatnot, so when layers come in the picture everything takes a long time.